# Disciplined badge for closed questions

Tags: support, badges, closed-questions, disciplined-badge

Does the disciplined badge also apply for closed questions?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, you can get the Disciplined badge for a closed question, whether you are deleting the question or an answer to the question.

The only requirement is that the post has at least +3 score, and is deleted by yourself. Neither of these are affected by closure, though do take into account that questions cannot be one-vote self-deleted if they have 2 or more answers or at least one upvoted answer; a closed question with a score of 3 or more is likely to have this.